# How do I add the Guidance spell to Fantasy Grounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fantasy-grounds

We've got our first 5e game coming up. I'm setting up my character sheet in [Fantasy Grounds](http://www.fantasygrounds.com/), and I'm trying to work out how to add the spells. In particular, I'm having trouble adding Guidance.

Guidance says:

> You touch one willing creature. Once before the spell ends, the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to one ability check of its choice. It can roll the die before or after making the ability check. The spell then ends.

So in Fantasy Grounds, I added an effect:

```
Description: 1d4
Targeting: Targets
Expend?: On next roll
```

I'm not sure I've got it correct though - does that look correct?

If it helps - raw XML from FG

```
    <id-00002>
        <actions>
            <id-00001>
                <apply type="string">roll</apply>
                <durmod type="number">0</durmod>
                <label type="string">SKILL: +1d4</label>
                <order type="number">1</order>
                <type type="string">effect</type>
            </id-00001>
        </actions>
        <cast type="number">0</cast>
        <castingtime type="string">1 action</castingtime>
        <components type="string">V,S</components>
        <description type="formattedtext">
            <p></p>
        </description>
        <duration type="string">Concentration, up to 1 minute</duration>
        <group type="string">Druid cantrip</group>
        <level type="number">0</level>
        <locked type="number">0</locked>
        <name type="string">Guidance</name>
        <prepared type="number">0</prepared>
        <range type="string">Touch</range>
        <school type="string">Divination</school>
        <shortdescription type="string">You touch one willing creature. Once before the spell ends, the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to one ability check of its choice. It can roll the die before or after making the ability check. The spell then ends.</shortdescription>
    </id-00002>
```

Comment: What specifically are you seeing that makes you wonder if you have it right?  Is it producing an odd output or a syntax error?  Is there any way for you to test it, maybe setting up a dummy campaign, with a token or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update to the most recent version of Fantasy Grounds you can open the library and open the SRD (you may have to get the DM to allow it) then drag the spells red dragon icon to the open Actions tab. It will add the spell.